# Why is the color of the same image different when displayed on laptop and mobile device

Tags: color-profile

I have created a banner with a pink background (so I thought) on my laptop. When I viewed the same image on my tablet and mobile phone the background was yellowish. My laptop runs Windows 8.1 where the Windows color system device profile is sRGB IEC61966-2.1. My tablet is a galaxy tab s and mobile phone is galaxy s4.

Comment: Well, usually you have to configure a new computer and tablet, for example brightness etc. Different screens, different configurations results in different colors ...

Comment: This is a fundamental physical limitation of color displays. Even the same screen will show different colors under different lighting conditions. Even changing the viewing angle can change color. The best you can hope for is that your colors are fairly close to what you want on the majority of screens.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so here is the thing I've learned from working in a room filled with screens from the same brand:

**No two screens are usually identical, when it comes to color.**

Normally, you'd have to adjust your screen colors manually, to get the "right" colors. Your average user will probably use the default settings and the ones who *do* choose to calibrate will typically do so with different settings, so one with a higher brightness, the other with less saturation, and so on

Such is also the case on other devices. Usually, you won't get the exact same result you were seeing while designing, being perfectly the same on all other devices.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there are many factors that can make your image look different from the screen you designed it on (brightness, calibration, light from the environment). However you can sometimes avoid your image being interpreted with the wrong profile, by making sure that the right profile is actually embedded to your image. Check Embed Color Profile when saving.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

On the one hand there is the issue of the profile. Your Phone/Tablet is probably using a different Profile than your laptop. On the other hand you'll always get different results in color on different screens, regardless of the profiles installed.

Best chances to get similar results on different machines is to use [Websafe Colors](http://websafecolors.info/) i guess.
hope this helps!

Comment: Web safe colors have nothing to do with this.

Comment: Websafe colors don't really help this situation, they are a legacy of the old days when many computers were only capable of displaying a 256 color palette. BUT the difference in the physical screens is definitely a big source of differences. A Samsung Galaxy device has an AMOLED display. The Windows tablet is likely using an LCD display. The differences in the underlying technology make it impossible to produce identical results.